# Can Windows 8 handle separate color profiles for multiple displays?

Tags: windows-8.1, display, multiple-monitors, colors, color-profiles

I'm currently using a laptop attached to an external monitor. I only ever use one of the displays at a time (external when at home, laptop when on the road). When I'm only using the external monitor, however, Windows 8.1 treats it as though it's the laptop display in terms of color management.

It seems to think the external monitor is the same as the laptop display, despite the fact they are listed as separate devices in the color management control panel. For example, when I select the laptop display (which is off) in the color management drop-down device list and change its default ICC profile, that affects the external monitor (which is on). Changing the default ICC profile for the external monitor does nothing.

Both displays (external monitor and laptop display) for some reason have the same "1|2" display number in that drop-down list -- "Display: 1|2. [device name]". if I click "identify monitors" the display I'm currently using is labeled "1|2". If both displays are used simultaneously (such as in extend screen mode) then they are correctly identified as either 1 or 2 and separate color profiles are applied as they should be to each monitor.

Anyone know why Windows is applying the default laptop display profile to an external monitor? Is this inability to switch profiles depending on the display in use something to do with the Intel GPU interfering with the Windows color management?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Are you calibrating with a hardware sensor?

Then: This depends on the GPU and how much LUTs (LookUp Tables) it has. You can easily test if your GPU has got enough (more than one) LUT:

Download this tool and open it: 
http://support.datacolor.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1431/90/gammatest---win

If you're able to turn magenta each monitor individually (just move GammaTest-window to the other screen to test), you have multiple LUTs. If instead both turn on magenta, then you have only one LUT in your GPU.

Comment: Yes, I'm calibrating with a hardware sensor (i1 Display) to create icc v2 profiles. The Magenta test works on both monitors (clear on one, magenta on other, vice versa, and both together), so there appear to be multiple LUTs supported. However, if the GPU supported only one LUT wouldn't that test also work if both monitors were using the same icc profile, which is what I suspect?

Comment: No, it would appear magenta on both.